# boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)

Tags: android, list, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get data from Shared Preferences and Inserting that data into List but it's getting me error. Although i have initialized the list but still it's getting this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

```
Information info = new Information(name, mobile, email, zone, type);
List<Information> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(getActivity());
listItems = sharedPrefManager.getDataFromSharedPreferences("info");
listItems.add(info);
sharedPrefManager.setDataToSharedPreferences("info", listItems);
```

Here is my SharedPrefManager getData Function

```
public List<Information> getDataFromSharedPreferences(String key) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String jsonPreferences = sharedPref.getString(key, null);

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Information>>() {
        }.getType();

        List<Information> contactList = gson.fromJson(jsonPreferences, type);
        return contactList;

    }
```

Comment: `sharedPref.getString(key, null);` Of course you're getting an NPE. If there's no String preference with the specified key, `jsonPreferences` will be null. You need to check that case and return an empty list if so.

Comment: thanks so much bro. wasted a whole day on figuring that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String jsonPreferences = sharedPref.getString(key, null);
```

Is the problematic line. The second parameter (where you're passing `null`), is the "def" parameter, ie what's returned by `getString()` if there is no preference stored matching the specified key.

Since the preference might not be set up, it's possible that `jsonPreferences` will be null (as is the case here). That means that

```
List<Information> contactList = gson.fromJson(jsonPreferences, type);
```

will fail, since you can't create any object from a null reference; Gson is trying to parse a null String.

You should add a null check below your `jsonPreferences` assignment:

```
String jsonPreferences = sharedPref.getString(key, null);
if (jsonPreferences == null || jsonPreferences.isEmpty()) return new ArrayList<Information>(); //return an empty list if there's no data; also checking for an empty String
```